# Guardar configuración de una App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo que guardar una serie de configuraciones para una **app**, mi idea inicial era hacerlo con **SQLite**(sqlite-net-pcl), pero al funcionar de forma asíncrona las pantalla donde he de usar las configuraciones no se cargan correctamente(a la primera).

Necesitaría una alternativa(Que pueda almacenar cualquier tipo de variables).

Comment: Podrias usar [`Preferences`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings?hl=es-419) aunque no te permite almacenar `DateTime`. De todas maneras, no entiendo cual es el problema con almacenar los datos en Sqlite

Answer (score 1):

Usa este plugin para guardar las preferencias de la App. lo debes de instalar por Nuget en todos los proyectos.

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin